# How to remove div backgrounds?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have an div element in website markup as follows.

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container" runat="server">
```

I have assigned it a css class as follows.

```
div#mainContainer.container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top:40px;
        height:500px;
        background:url("../img/bgimg.png")no-repeat;
    }
```

Now after a button click I want to remove only the background of that div and don't want to tamper any positioning of elements inside it. And btw I am using ASP.net to create this website. How can I do that ?

Comment: do you want to do this via javascript, or in a server-side event?

Comment: Please explain in great detail what you've tried so we can better assist you.

Comment: sorry for very brief description earlier. Please check updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this in a server-side event, you'll need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to your `<div>` element, and it will need an `id` attribute. This will make it easy to alter server-side.

You'll need an event-handler method in your code-behind for the button click.

In this event handler, do something like (this assumes the `id` of your `<div>` is "container")

```
container.Style["background"] = String.Empty;
```

However, in your question, you say you've assigned your element a *class*. If this is the case, the above might not work. It might be easiest to define another CSS class without this background image rule, and then in the code-behind do this:

```
container.Attributes["class"] = "newClass";
```

Comment: Yes, I want to do very similar. I tried your solution but it's not working. btw I added following line in button click event.   mainContainer.Style["background"] = String.Empty;

Answer (score 1):

Now with pure `CSS`.

```
.button{
   background:green;
}
.background-class{
    background:red;
}

.button:active + .background-class{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AX8tY/

Comment: @Madmartigan please point my mistake because i didn't much experience in js.

Comment: In that case I suggest you don't offer any answers that involve js/jquery, especially in a rush to be the first answer. I see you fixed `$(div)`, but you still have 2 more. `function` needs `()` as always, and you need to decide how you're passing arguments to `css()`. Either comma separated or in object notation... not mixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

If your HTML is something like this:

```
<button class="your-button" />
<div class="background-class">
    ...
</div>
```

Then your JS might look something like this (this assumes you're also using jQuery):

```
$(".your-button").click(function(){
    $(".background-class").removeClass("background-class");
});
```

**EDIT :** I just saw in your comment that you'd like to use a server-side event. This is a client-side solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript (either direct or some JavaScript framework like jQuery) and set the CSS style to

```
background:none
```

This means you could alter the style of the specific instance or you could define a new CSS class to apply.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple javascript as:
`onclick="javascript:getElementById('div_element_id').style.backgroundImage = '';"`
or you may use jQuery's API aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you could try something like this :

```
$('button#idButton').click(function{
$('div#idDiv').css('background':'none')
});
```

If you don't use jquery you should implement a javascript function on the onClick event, try something like :

```
<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" onClick="javascript:deleteBackground()" />
<script>
function deleteBackground(){
Document.getElementById('div_element_id').style.backgroundImage = ''; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you defined a class

```
.yourclassname {
   background: url('..');
}
```

you can also use the remove class function

```
$('div').removeClass('yourclassname');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetClass() {
        var ID = document.getElementById('<%=mainContainer.ClientID %>');

        ID.className += " ChangeBackground";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#mainContainer.container
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
        height: 500px;
        background: url("wallpaper-1554220.jpg")no-repeat;
    }

    .ChangeBackground
    {
        background: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return SetClass();" runat="server" Text="Change CSS"/>
```